# How can I change the display to show current shot number on my Canon 600D?

Tags: camera-settings, canon-600d

How can I change the display "Number of possible shots" to "Current shot number" on my Canon 600D?

I need to record extra notes on each image taken, and it would be convenient to have that quickly available.

Answer (score 2):

Canon has not provided a way to change the "Number of possible shots'  to any other measurement.

This is of course the equivalent to the number of frames remaining from a roll of film. In that context, the  number of shots was not something the camera could calculate, since it didn't know the length of film (24, 36, etc) in the roll.

Today, the camera is estimating the shots by the size of the card, but the number of shots taken isn't really a meaningful number, other than just keeping score.

**If you want to quickly know how many shots you have taken,** and you started with an empty card, its very easy to get this number:

Simply press the 'play' button to view your shots, and if it doesn't come up, then press 'info'. It will display the number of shots taken, with the current shot number.

[image]

In the bottom left hand corner of this shot, you see "4/4". This is the 4th image of 4 taken. So total of 4 photos taken since the card was emptied. If you do not empty the card before the shoot, then this doesn't work as well of course.

Comment: Hi, let me explain as such.  I do astrophotography, and take numerous shots changing iso/time/object/focus etc.  So I need to make notes of the shots i.e. #27-55 iso 1600 30sec Omega cluster, so that it is easy to select the images for post-processing.  The display "Number of possible shots" changes differently due to the length of the shot and is not helpful to me.

Comment: Great,thats why I have shown how to keep track of how many shots you have taken

Comment: Ideally I would like to see the shot number in the LCD screen where it displays "Number of possible shots".  Even when using "Remote live view" I cannot see the shot number...

Comment: @JohnGill Note that ISO and shutter length are encoded in the image's EXIF metadata.  That doesn't help with the "omega cluster" part, but may save you some time and effort.